# PHP mysqli_query not working on actual hosting server

Tags: php, mysqli

My following code is working on my local host server. when I host it to actual server the query is not working though connection was established. 

output was

> "result problem"

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php'; 

class test{
    public function test1(){
        $db_connect = new db_connect();
        $con = $db_connect->connect();
        if(!$con){
            echo "connection fail";
        }else{
            $sql = "select * from tbl_admin where name='abc' ";
            $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            if(!$query){
                    echo "result problem";
                }else{
                        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                        echo $result['ad_tp'];
                    }
        }
    }
}

$t = new test();
$t->test1();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have setup database and table in host server?

Comment: use this :  instead of "echo result problem"; use echo "mysqli query error " . $mysqli_error($con);

Comment: Yest i'm sure... i have imported db from my localhost exactly. it is in the db.

Comment: thanx daniel B. it says "Function name must be a string in test.php on line 14". Line 14 is "echo "mysqli query error " . $mysqli_error($con);"

Comment: Use it like this `$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: and it should be  `mysqli_error($con);` not `$mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: Try to echo the query and run that query on database and see if It is working .

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
echo "result problem";
```

with

```
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
```

This will get you an exact idea of why query is not executing.

Comment: Thanx Arpita;It printed only "Errormessage:"  wot's the meaning of "Function name must be a string in test.php on line 14" line 14 is "echo "mysqli query error " . $mysqli_error($con);"

Comment: Remove $ from $mysqli_error from line 14

Comment: Thanx Rumi.. it does not show any error... $ part should be there..

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's `mysqli_error` to find the MySQL error:

```
if(!$query){
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: thanx Rahautos. nothing had happen